# Proof that {$\frac{1}{b_n}$} is bounded and $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{1}{b_n}$=$\frac{1}{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I need help/suggestions for improvements for a task, that I try to solve as a preparation for my exam.

Let {${b_n}$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence with $b_n \neq 0$ $\forall$ n $\in\mathbb{N}$ and ${\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$ >0. Show that the sequence {${\frac{1}{b_n}}$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and $$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}=\frac{1}{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$$

a) Show that the sequence is $\frac{1}{b_n}$ is bounded: Well we know ${b_n}$ is bounded with L=${\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$ >0. So we have $$0<L<b_n<S={\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$$ Since $\frac{1}{b_n}\leq \frac{1}{L}$ and $\frac{1}{b_n}\geq \frac{1}{S}$. We get $$\frac{1}{S}\leq \frac{1}{b_n}\leq \frac{1}{L}$$ Thus {${\frac{1}{b_n}}$} is bounded.

Is this proof correct?

b)Let L= ${\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$ and M=$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$.

L= ${\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $b_n<L + \epsilon$ (dividing by L+$\epsilon$) $\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{L+\epsilon}$<$\frac{1}{b_n}$. Since L + $\epsilon$ is fixed, we get$\frac{1}{L+\epsilon}$$\leq$M=$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$.

Doing exactly the same with M=$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$, we get L= ${\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}$ $\leq$$\frac{1}{M-\epsilon}$.

We let $\epsilon \rightarrow$ 0 and get $M\geq \frac{1}{L}$ and $M\leq\frac{1}{L}$. Thus $$M=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}= \frac{1}{L}= \frac{1}{{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}}$$

Is this proof correct? The problem with my approach. We know L=infX $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon$>0 $\exists$ $x\in X$ with $x<L + \epsilon$. Are we allowed to replace infX with $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$X ? Also, am I allowed to divide with $L + \epsilon$ ? L could be smaller than $\epsilon$. Maybe I should write straightaway, that we let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$....

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but isn't $b_n=1/n$ bounded and $\neq 0 \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Diger jep ${b_n}$ is bounded with b_n= \frac{1}{n}. However I don't believe that using this example as $b_n$ would be sufficient. But thats doesn't matter since I believe that a) is correct. I am really unsure with b though.

Answer (score 1):

Just some minor points:

In **a)** you should write $\forall \epsilon>0,\epsilon<L$
$$0<\underbrace{\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n}_{L>0}-\epsilon < b_n < \underbrace{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n}_{S}+\epsilon$$
for almost all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $\forall n\geq N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, because it could be possible that no $b_n$ satisfies $b_n \geq L$ or $b_n \leq S$ (see discussion below). Since $b_n>0$, it is clear that for the finitely many $b_n$ with $n<N$ you still have boundedness of $1/b_n$.

For **b)** I'm not quite sure what you do there. If you fix $n$ by saying $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$, you can not take the limit (what limit for some fixed $n$?). I guess you need to work with subsequences here, i.e. there exists a subsequence $a_k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ it follows $$b_{a_k} < L + \epsilon \\
\frac{1}{b_{a_k}} > \frac{1}{L+\epsilon} \,.$$
You will still find $b_n$ that violate this inequality, but these $b_n$ do not give any information about the $\limsup$ (since they are actually smaller) and so you can say $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{b_{n}}=\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{b_{a_k}}>\frac{1}{L+\epsilon} \,.$$
Similarly, we clearly know $b_n>L-\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ (this time) and so $$\frac{1}{b_n} < \frac{1}{L-\epsilon}\\
\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{b_n} < \frac{1}{L-\epsilon}\,.$$ Since this is true $\forall \epsilon>0$, the result follows.

Comment: I just thought that if M= supX $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists a $x \in X$ with x>M-$\epsilon$ (the defintion of supremum) then we could do the same with M= lim sup X......

Also, are we allowed to divide with (L-$\epsilon$)? Could be 0 or smaller than 0...

Comment: $L>0$ maybe small, but we can always pick a smaller $\epsilon>0$ (that is what's relevant here). I'm still not sure I get what you are saying with this supX. If there is only 1 $x\in X$ for which $x>M-\epsilon$, then there is no point in taking the $\limsup$. You need infinitely many $x\in X$.

Comment: However, it is true that if $M=\sup X$, then there maybe only 1 $x\in X$ for which $x>M-\epsilon$. For $\limsup$ this is different, you need infinitely many. This is because if $\limsup$ exists, you must have a subsequence that converges to this $\limsup$. Recall the definition of $\limsup b_n$ as $\sup\{b_k | k\geq n\}$.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right. What I still don't understand is... why is $b_n \geq$ lim inf $b_n$ for some n.... I mean its the lowest limit of $b_n$, so it should be valid for all n?  I probably have a wrong image of the limes superior and the limes infimum...

Comment: $b_n \geq \liminf b_n$ for almost all $n$, not all. Think of the infimum of all $b_k$ for $k\geq n$ and then take the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: $\liminf -1/n$ is still $0$.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what this task has to do with 1/n. There is no limes inferior for $b_n= \frac{1}{n}$. $\frac{1}{n}$ has an infimum.

Comment: Maybe this example is not good, but in any case $$\inf_{k\geq n} \frac{-1}{k} = -\frac{1}{n} \, , $$ then take the limit, which is $0$.

Comment: For this particular $b_n=\frac{-1}{n}$, you have that no $b_n$ satisfies $b_n \geq \liminf b_n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134406/discussion-between-analysis-mark-and-diger).